# How should I handle header files in a bundle?

Tags: objective-c, nsbundle

I want to develop a program that relies on plugins (here: loadable bundles) to work. Multiple plugins are asked to use the same `AFNetworking` ressource to make network requests. However, I don't know where to put `AFNetworking` and `CustomPluginProtocol` headers.

Here is how my program structure looks like for now:

```
MyApp.xcodeproj
  - AFNetworking
    - Header.h
  - Plugins
    - Plugin1.xcodeproj
      - PrincipalClass.m
    - Plugin2.xcodeproj
      - PrincipalClass.m
  - Classes
    - CustomPluginProtocol.h
    - MainClass.m
```

Of course, every `principalClass` from `PluginN` complies to the `CustomPluginProtocol`.

- Do the headers have to be copied in each bundle ?
- Can I just include the main program `AFNetworking` headers from my plugins ? If so (and that's what I do for now), I don't have any completion. How can I get it ?

---

#### Edit

Ok, so maybe I wasn't clear in my question.

I want my plugins to use sources from the main application, let's say `CommonClass.m` and `CommonClass.h`. Do the plugins need `CommonClass.h` in their bundle, and if not, how do I enable completion when I'm in the plugin scope ?

Comment: Headers files doesn't get added to the bundle.  Unless you are adding a file as a resource.

Comment: Each plugin project that need AFNetworking would link against that library.

Comment: `AFNetworking` is not a real library as it is not compiled separately from my main application. It's just a bunch of files in a folder. How to make `PluginN` see `AFNetworking` headers properly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1) Produce a framework which includes the headers in `<Your Framework>/Headers/`

2) Simply give out the headers to developers

I prefer option 1 as it's easier to understand and keep track of everything, but apps like Photoshop use option 2 all the time, so it's perfectly viable. With Option 1, developers would add the framework you make to their Xcode project, and the would `#include <FrameworkName/HeaderName.h>`. With option 2, you would give them a folder of headers and they would put it someplace that's convenient for them and then would add that to their header search paths and `#include "FolderName/HeaderName.h"`.